# Error while using malloc and FILE pointer together

Tags: c, file, pointers, malloc

So, what I am trying to do is initialize an unsigned integer buffer and also using a file pointer(FILE *fp) to read from a file and store the contents of the file in the above mentioned buffer

The thing is that the problem doesn't occur when I don't use malloc() and define the buffer as an unsigned integer array instead

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 10000

void main()
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    unsigned int *buffer = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)*SIZE);
    unsigned int c;
    unsigned int length = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen("testfn.c", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("\nFile not found.\nExiting...");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        buffer[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    length = i;
    printf("\nNumber of elements= %d\n", length);

    for (i = 0; i <= length; ++i)
        printf("%c ", buffer[i]);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

The expected output are the contents of the file stored as integers and printed on the screen.

What I am receiving is a segmentation fault and no output.

Comment: What is the length of the file?

Comment: That's a great opportunity to start learning how to use a debugger. Run your program in a debugger and it should show you where the segfault happens. Then check variables for expected content.

Comment: Assuming the length is correct and matches the length of your array, you never loop until your control variable in the loop equals the length. You want to loop until it equals length - 1, since arrays start at index 0.

Comment: Do you want to read single characters or space separated `int`s or a binary file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193099/discussion-between-ahmed-masud-and-ctx).

Comment: Found it! It was the 'i' in the while loop.

Comment: I just added && i<SIZE to the while condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone!